# tikz Commutative Diagrams - Compiling and Best Practice

Tags: tikz-pgf, commutative-diagrams

Newcomers wanting to use TikZ to create commutative diagrams face a varied (non-uniform) approach. 
I found this simple method to create a commutative diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

$$\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
  \node (C) {$C$};
  \node (P) [below of=C] {$\prod_{i \in I} A_i$};
  \node (Ai) [right of=P] {$A_i$};
  \draw[->] (C) to node {$f_i$} (Ai);
  \draw[->, dashed] (C) to node [swap] {$\langle f_i \rangle_{i \in I}$} (P);
  \draw[->] (P) to node [swap] {$\pi_i$} (Ai);
\end{tikzpicture}$$

\end{document}
```

Which produces a neat commutative diagram:
[image: Diagram from code above]

I wished to adapt this for my own commutative diagram. The code is as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

$$\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
  \node (V) {$V$};
  \node (FAI) [right of= V] {$FAI(V)$};
  \node (CL) [below of= FAI] {$CL(V,q)$};
  \draw[->] (V) to node (FAI);
  \draw[->, dashed] (FAI) to node (CL);
  \draw[->] (V) to node (CL);
\end{tikzpicture}$$

\end{document}
```

However, my diagram produces the compile error: "Package tikz Error: (, +, coordinate, pic, or node expected."

Reading on TeX, I have noticed users recommend alternative methods to draw commutative diagrams.

1. What are current best practices (best packages to use, etc.)
2. How do I use these best practise methods to accomplish my (simple) commutative diagram?

Comment: Why don't use just use `tikz-cd` instead of doing it by hand? Regarding your code, I don't recall ever seeing `to node (..)` before. I'd probably just use `--` instead. Also never use `$$...$$`, it is not LaTeX.

Comment: @daleif kind user preceded me by a minute. In fact I voted for your comment.

Comment: You could read [Difference between “right of=” and “right=of” in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here there is my version with [`tikz-cd`](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf). It is very easy to create simple and complex commutative diagrams.

Advice: do not worry about the background because It does not appear. Your initial code it is into this [link](https://pdp7.org/blog/2011/02/how-to-draw-commutative-diagrams-in-latex-with-tikz/).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
V \arrow[r] \arrow[rdd] & FAI(V) \arrow[dd, dotted] \\
 &  \\
 & CL(V,q)
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
C \arrow[d, "\langle f_i \rangle_{i \in I}"', dotted] \arrow[rd, "f_i"] &  \\
\prod_{i \in I} A_i \arrow[r, "\pi_i"'] & A_i
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just wondering, where does that in the background in the images come from? and what is up with the `"'` in the last code example?

Comment: It is to align the labels on the left and bottom.

Answer (score 7):

Your code was almost correct, you just forgot the text label of the node.

Yours was like this:

```
\draw[->] (V) to node (FAI);
```

but it must be like this:

```
\draw[->] (V) to node {} (FAI);
```

or like this: (thanks @PaulGaborit)

```
\draw[->] (V) to (FAI);
```

I made three of these corrections.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

$$\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
  \node (V) {$V$};
  \node (FAI) [right of= V] {$FAI(V)$};
  \node (CL) [below of= FAI] {$CL(V,q)$};
  \draw[->] (V) to (FAI);% corrected here
  \draw[->, dashed] (FAI) to (CL);% here
  \draw[->] (V) to (CL);% and here
\end{tikzpicture}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be more appropriate to delete all empty nodes (`node {}`).

Comment: Good work. +1 for your answer.